# When does this integral converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

So I'd like to find out for which values of $a,b>0$ the following integral is well-defined and how that will change if the absolute value is removed? Thanks!

$I = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{|\sin(x^a)|}{x^b}dx $

Comment: well-defined means its not an improper integral. For any positive value of $a$ and $b$ the integral will be improper, since $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined. If $a = 0$, then any value of $b$ > 0 will make the integral improper. Thus, only if $a = b = 0$, the integral will never be improper.

Comment: I presume what is really wanted is for which values the improper integral **converges**. It's always improper, because $x$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: But it's not a function of $x$.  Perhaps you mean $f(a,b)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you really want to know for which values the improper integral **converges**, and you mean $f(a,b)$, not $f(x)$.

The change of variables $t = x^a$ gives you

$$f(a,b) = \dfrac{1}{a} \int_0^\infty |\sin(t)|\; t^p\; dt$$

where $p = (1-a-b)/a$.  For convergence at $\infty$ you need $p < -1$, and for convergence at $0$ (where $\sin(t) \approx t$) you need $p > -2$.
With $a > 0$ this is equivalent to $1 < b < a + 1$.

On the other hand, without the absolute value the integral converges  as long as $-2 < p < 0$, using Dirichlet's test.  In fact we can even get a closed form:

$$ \int_0^\infty \sin(t)\; t^p\; dt = \cos(\pi p/2)\; \Gamma(1+p)$$

Comment: How did you arrive at this p substitution?

Comment: Useful principle: integrals involving trig functions of $t$ are usually easier to deal with than those involving trig functions of some function of $x$.